# Inheritance with templates in C++?

Tags: python, c++, oop, templates, inheritance

Let's imagine I want to write a generic class `Point` and a specialized class `Point2D` with two new accessors: `getX()` and `getY()`. In Python I would probably write something like this:

```
class Point(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        list.__init__(self, args)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(*[a + b for a, b in zip(self, other)])

    def __str__(self):
        return 'P(' + repr(self)[1:-1] + ')'

class Point2D(Point):
    @property
    def get_x(self):
        return self[0]

p = Point2D(1,2,3)
q = Point2D(3,4,5)
c = p + q
print(f"{c} = {p} + {q}")
print(c.get_x)
```

But in C++. I discovered that inheritance with templates is cumbersome. [cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) mentioned the CRTP pattern, so I wrote this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename C, typename T, int N>
class PointCRTP
{
   protected:
    array<T, N> elements;

   public:
    PointCRTP() = default;
    PointCRTP(array<T, N> el) : elements(el) {}

    C operator+(C& other)
    {
        C c;
        transform(elements.begin(), elements.end(), other.elements.begin(),
                  c.elements.begin(), plus<int>());
        return c;
    }

    T operator[](int k) { return elements[k]; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, C const& x)
    {
        os << "P(";
        for (auto k : x.elements) os << k << ", ";
        return os << "\b\b" << ')';
    }
};

template <typename T, int N>
struct Point : public PointCRTP<Point<T, N>, T, N> {
    using PointCRTP<Point<T, N>, T, N>::PointCRTP;
};

template <typename T>
struct Point2D : public PointCRTP<Point2D<T>, T, 2> {
    Point2D() = default;
    Point2D(T x, T y) : PointCRTP<Point2D<T>, T, 2>({x, y}) {}

    T getX() { return PointCRTP<Point2D<T>, T, 2>::elements[0]; }
    T getY() { return PointCRTP<Point2D<T>, T, 2>::elements[1]; }
};

int main()
{
    Point<int, 3> p({1, 2, 3});
    Point<int, 3> q({3, 4, 2});
    Point<int, 3> c = p + q;
    std::cout << c << " = " << p << " + " << q << endl;

    Point2D<int> r(1, 2);
    Point2D<int> s(3, 4);
    Point2D<int> t = r + s;
    std::cout << t << " = " << r << " + " << s << endl;
}
```

I am not very happy for several reasons:

- It is cumbersome
- It looks ugly
- I have to redefine all the constructors

How would I improve this?

Comment: Are you aware of the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) approach? That might solve your problem.

Comment: You can use `using` for the constructors but yes you probably do need to redefine the operators

Comment: You probably shouldn't inherit from a class that is passed around and returned *by value*, this is dangerous and error-prone. This is independent from the language you are using. You may want to define a stand-alone function `toString` instead. BTW C++ is not an object-oriented language, it is a multi-paradigm language that supports OOP among other things. The class you are looking at is not object-oriented as it lacks virtual functions.

Comment: @DavisHerring This example is just an academic example. I would like to have a derived class with additional methods in the case both Base and Derived are templates. The main issue is that I would like to minimize the redundancy (being DRY) and I've read the only solution in C++ is to use CRTP. Am I wrong?

Comment: @nowox:Of course you don’t have to use CRTP to have one class template inherit from another (to use a slightly colloquial description).  Even your Python example doesn’t support `(Point2D(1,0)+Point2D(2,1)).get_x`, so you’ll have to say what behavior it is you want to have.

Comment: @DavisHerring You were right so I updated my question